# Creating a CSV file based on GTM Triggers

Tags: html, database, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have created in my html website several kind of Google Tag Manager triggers, right now i follow them using only the GTM dashboard and Google analytics. What i want is to create a csv database based on those triggers meaning - for each visitor i will have a row with an ID, with the google tag manager triggers as columns and values based on the info on the data layer and whether or not the trigger was fired.

I'm not that sure from where should i approach this issue, and if I'm not utilizing GTM or Google Analytics properly, i would love to hear about it. Thanks.